# Rails 4 - Send Json to google maps to show markers (not using a gem)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, google-maps-api-3

I have my "location" model. In this model I have address, city, postal_code, latitude, longitude, of the users.

What I need is to send all this data in json format. Then, I will use google maps api in order to show the markers in the map and in some way show the near stores (of the client) using your geolocation.

This is my locations_controller index:

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @locations }
  end
end
```

In application layout I have the googlpe maps api call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js
```

And in my views/locations/index.htmlerb tengo el mapa:

```
<div style='width: 100%;'>
    <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto;'></div>
</div>
```

And then, this is a the javascript calling "locations.json" that we are trying to use.

```
var map;
var arrMarkers = [];
var arrInfoWindows = [];

function mapInit(){
    var centerCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -97); 
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: centerCoord,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    $.getJSON("/locations.json", {}, function(json){
        $.each(json, function(i,item){
            $("#markers").append('<li><a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + item.location.address + '</a></li>');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.latitude, item.location.longitude),
                map: map,
                title: item.location.country
            });
            arrMarkers[i] = marker;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<h3>"+ item.place.cirty +"</h3><p>"+ item.location.postal_code + "&nbsp;" +  item.location.city + ", &nbsp;" + "</p>",
                maxWidth: 100   
            });
            arrInfoWindows[i] = infowindow;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });
    });

}
$(function(){
    // initialize map (create markers, infowindows and list)
    mapInit();

    // "live" bind click event
    $("#markers a").live("click", function(){
        var i = $(this).attr("rel");
        arrInfoWindows[i].open(map, arrMarkers[i]);
    });
});
```

All this is not working, I don't know what else I need to do or is I need to do this in other way.

I will appreciate any help